# clickonce uninstall version in publish.html

Tags: clickonce

I have created an app called APP1 and publish it using click once.

After a while I created an updated version, called it APP2 and also publish it using click once with a different url.

after seeing that everything is OK with APP2 I want that users opening APP1 will get a message saying they need to move to APP2 with the URL.

I also want to uninstall APP1 automatically.

How can i do it in the publish.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the message and the link to the new version in a new version so the user download the new ap version and gets the msg